# Construct picture of person's face from DNA

Tags: dna-sequencing, genomics

Would it be possible to construct a picture of a person's face from his/her DNA?

Comment: Apparently so:
http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004224
Did you not try a google search before asking?

Comment: There's a TED talk from a top researcher on that subject, his answer is YES the science of that is advancing alot. https://www.ted.com/talks/riccardo_sabatini_how_to_read_the_genome_and_build_a_human_being